# malformed entry in sources.list error when trying to install albert

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, updates

I had tried to install Albert on ubuntu by using the following codes. The Ubuntu version I have is 20.04

```
curl https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:manuelschneid3r/public_key | sudo apt-key add -

echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/-manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04//' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list

sudo wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key -O "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc"

sudo apt update

sudo apt install Albert
```

But I got this error:

```
Desktop:~$ sudo apt update
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Now everytime I open my terminal and try to install some package and use sudo apt update. I get the above error.

I've reset and cleared the terminal, but I still get the same error. How can I clear the terminal so that I can work on terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Visiting [the URL you provided for the repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/-manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/) in a browser results in this response:

[image: Resource is no longer available!]

As a result, there's little chance of installing Albert from that location.

**HOWEVER**, if you ditch the `-` in the URL and use this:

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/
```

Then it will work.

So, with this in mind, edit your `manuelschneid3r.list` file like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit the `.list` file with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** You may want to do something about that file name. Rather than `home:manuelschneid3r.list`, perhaps rename it to `manuelschneid3r.list`</sup>
2. Edit the URL, to remove the erroneous dash. The file should now look like:

   ```
   deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/ /
   ```
3. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

From here, you should be able to install Albert.

<sub>[Source](https://albertlauncher.github.io/installing/)</sub>

Comment: You mean `sudo apt update' in point 3, right ?